# Beginner to C Programming - .c file that will operate outside of console / terminal and interact with GUI?

Tags: c, io, output

I'm several months into learning C programming and so far have used .c files that always output to the console. Can someone suggest a sample .c file with code that would interact with the GUI? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you're asking "How do I code a C program that has a graphical interface, instead of a text-mode command line?"  There is no "one, standard" library - you have many, many choices.  Two options include [Xlib](http://xopendisplay.hilltopia.ca/2009/Jan/Xlib-tutorial-part-1----Beginnings.html) or [GTK](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-gui-in-c-programming-using-gtk-toolkit/)

Comment: To implement a GUI under C you'll need to find and learn a C-based GUI API.  If you want a Linux-specific one, try looking here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717138/what-is-linux-s-native-gui-api/